# Accessing a function of stateful widget in its state class? flutter

Tags: dart, widget, flutter, statefulwidget

I am trying to call _signOut function after the onPressed method for logout button. However it doesnt (recognize the function or let me call it) I can however make a call widget.Onsignedout, a callback to it parent and everything works as intended. except i sign out the user at auth.signout and call back is just to update the form. how can I access the _signOut() from state class? thank you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_demo/auth.dart';
import 'package:login_demo/root_page.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({this.auth, this.onSignedOut});
  final BaseAuth auth;
  //To call a function of a parent, you can use the callback pattern
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;

  void _signOut() async {
    try {
      Text('Signing Out here');
      await auth.signOut();
      onSignedOut;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Homepage'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              'Logout',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)
            ),
            onPressed: widget.onSignedOut,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Welcome',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to make your method public. Right now because of the underscore (`_`) before the name, the method is private and you cannot access it.

Simply change the name from `_signOut` to `signOut` and then you should be able to call it by `widget.signOut()`.

Comment: making the method public didn't seem to work, I get the error. "Expression here is a type of 'void' and therefore cannot be used. If I add "auth.signOut();" to the callback onSignedout method. it seems to work.

Comment: If you are doing  
`onPressed: widget.signOut`  
try changing it to
`onPressed: () => widget.signOut()`
and tell me if it works :)

Also what you can do is remove `void` from `signOut()` method since it will return a `Future`

Comment: I actually ended up moving the function down stateful state section and passing the two parameters through the stateful constructor. I read somewhere it was good practice.

Answer (score 0):

First, change your `_signOut` to `signOut` so it can be accessed by another file. OR more simple solution, move your function inside the `state` of your homepagestate statefulWidget.

Comment: Do not copy-paste someone answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).