# Pass a function to the state of a stateless widget flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to do the exact same thing that poster in the following question about passing a function to the State of a a Stateful widget: [Accessing a function of stateful widget in its state class? flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720835/accessing-a-function-of-stateful-widget-in-its-state-class-flutter)

In this example (same one I'm working on and likely from the same youtube video), how do I move the function down to the stateful state section and passing the two parameters through the stateful constructor?

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Provide some code pls

Comment: Why do you even what that? Just pass it to the StatefulWidget and call it from the state using `widget.myCallback(...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Passing Function to StatelessWidget not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59668442/flutter-passing-function-to-statelesswidget-not-working)

Comment: I flagged your question as "asked before", but it turns out that you were in fact the first to ask, although no one dared to write a detailed answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function callback to the StatelessWidget during initialization. That's my approach on initializing an ActionMenu that calls its functions from the parent class.

```dart
late ActionMenu actionMenu;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // Initialize ActionMenu
  // arguments passed are Home Screen functions
  // that can be in ActionMenu class
  actionMenu = ActionMenu(this.settings, this.logout);
}

settings(){
  // TODO
}

logout(){
  // TODO
}
```

...and on the ActionMenu. You can now call the functions inside the StatelessWidget.

```dart
enum MenuOptions { menuSettings, menuLogout }

class ActionMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function menuSettings, menuLogout;
  ActionMenu(this.menuSettings, this.menuLogout);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton<MenuOptions>(
      onSelected: (MenuOptions value) {
        switch (value) {
          case MenuOptions.menuSettings:
            this.menuSettings();
            break;
          case MenuOptions.menuLogout:
            this.menuLogout();
            break;
        }
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>>[
        PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
          value: MenuOptions.menuSettings,
          child: Text('Settings'),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
          value: MenuOptions.menuLogout,
          child: Text('Logout'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```