# Flutter - Passing Function to StatelessWidget not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a Generic ConfirmWidget, but it's not working. This is my code:
My idea is to pass an "Any Function" when my custom widget is invoked.

```
class ConfirmWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final BuildContext context;
  final String mensaje;
  final Function btnSi;

  ConfirmWidget({this.context, this.mensaje, this.btnSi});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text(mensaje),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          child: new Text("No"),
        ),
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            btnSi == null ? Navigator.of(context).pop(true):btnSi;
          },
          child: new Text("Si"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

My Widget being used:

```
Future<bool> confirmCancelar(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => new ConfirmWidget(
        mensaje: "¿Está seguro de cancelar la operación?",
        context: context,
        btnSi:()=>Navigator.pop(context),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of passing function, why don't you pass value and use it to determine the action.

Comment: what is not working? the dialog is not dismissed?

Comment: I was passing my own function, but... <<btnSi == null ? Navigator.of(context).pop(true):btnSi>> the problem is that i am not calling the function correctly. This is the correct way: <<btnSi == null ? Navigator.of(context).pop(true):btnSi()>>... It works now... thanks u all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not binding it directly to the onPressed event, you need to call the function.
Try this:

```
    new FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        btnSi == null ? Navigator.of(context).pop(true):btnSi();
      },
      child: new Text("Si"),
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `Function` to `VoidCallback`. I have an example widget.

```
class CircleIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double size;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final IconData icon;
  final Color iconColor;

  CircleIconButton(
      {this.size = 32, @required this.icon, @required this.onPressed, this.iconColor = Colors.blue});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(size * 2),
      child: Material(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: this.onPressed,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Icon(
              icon,
              color: iconColor,
              size: size * 0.66, // 66% width for icon
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

used like

```
CircleIconButton(
            icon: Icons.search,
            onPressed: _searchProduct,
          )
```

Comment: I'm getting `A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'void Function()' in a const constructor.
Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword` any ideas?

Comment: Also, getting: `The values in a const list literal must be constants.
Try removing the keyword 'const' from the list literal.`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this with the latest version is to change the variable type `Function` to `Function()`.

Example:

This is your `StatelessWidget`

```
class ConfirmWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final BuildContext context;
  final String mensaje;
  final Function btnSi;

  ConfirmWidget({this.context, this.mensaje, this.btnSi});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text(mensaje),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          child: new Text("No"),
        ),
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            btnSi == null ? Navigator.of(context).pop(true):btnSi;
          },
          child: new Text("Si"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This will be the updated `StatelessWidget`

```
class ConfirmWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final BuildContext context;
  final String mensaje;
  final Function() btnSi; //UPDATED WAY TO PUT IT

  ConfirmWidget({this.context, this.mensaje, this.btnSi});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text(mensaje),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          child: new Text("No"),
        ),
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: btnSi, //JUST LIKE THIS
          child: new Text("Si"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```